# FLAC.framework error

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

I am trying to learn how to use SFML however when i try to compile my c++ code i get Xcode telling me`Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2`. this is the error i get when i click more info

> ditto: can't get real path for source
>   '/Library/Frameworks/FLAC.framework' couldn't copy
>   /Library/Frameworks/FLAC.framework to
>   /Users/tris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/idk-ckysmijtsswdysecxtelmnggzhun/Build/Products/Debug/idk.app/Contents/Frameworks//FLAC.framework
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

how would i go about fixing this? i have tried reinstalling the Command line tools packaged with xcode.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error with the way i had installed SFML. If anyone comes across this error then please go back and install the dylib option of sfml. that is how my issue was resolved.